# Probability: $N$ dependent Bernoulli trials?

Tags: probability, distributions, expected-value

I understand the proof, but I don't see why *Bernoulli trials are mutually independent [...]* is not necessary.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a derivation of expected value of binomial distribution, i.e. distribution of sum of independent Bernoulli random variables. The highlighted comment seems to say that in some other part of the book they will show that the independence assumption is not needed. So it seems that you should rather quote the other part of the book is you don't understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expected value operator has a linearity property which means that the expected value of a sum is always equal to the sum of the individual expected values.  This property holds regardless of the dependence between the terms in the sum.  So if $X = B_1 + \cdots + B_n$ is a sum of Bernoulli trials $B_i \sim \text{Bern}(p)$ then, by the linearity property you have:

$$\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}\Bigg( \sum_{i=1}^n B_i \Bigg) =  \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}(B_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n p = np.$$

The quoted section shown in your question obtains this result by a different method, using the fact that $X \sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$ in the case where the trials are independent.  However, as you can see, the result holds even in the case where independence does not hold.